# Moving cursor to the end inserted content

Tags: vba, ms-word

How do I move cursor to the end of inserted content after executing `InsertFile()` on a `Range` object (not `Selection` object)?

### Detail

I'm receiving a `Range` object from the caller. Currently `Range.Start` and `Range.End` are set to the same value (i.e. Range object doesn't contain any text and just acting as the *insertion point*). I need to execute `InsertFile()` at that cursor location and then move the cursor to the end of inserted content. The content is an HTML file. Looks like calling `InsertFile()` does not affect `Range.Start` or `Range.End`.

Since this is an HTML file, I can't use inserted content's length too.

Comment: Before you insert the file add a temporary bookmark at the point you want the cursor to be moved to afterwards. After inserting the file move to bookmarked location and delete the bookmark.

Answer (score 0):

You could, for example, use code like:

```
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Selection.Range
With Rng
  .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  .InsertFile FileName:="File to insert", Link:=True
  .End = .End + 1
  .End = .Fields(1).Result.End
  .Fields.Unlink
  .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
End With
```